# Visualizar form quando a senha for definida

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tem esse codigo :

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script>
      function validarSenha(){
        senha1 = document.f1.senha1.value
        senha2 = document.f1.senha2.value

        if (senha1 == senha2) {
        alert("PASS OK");
                document.getElementbyId("cadastro").style.visibility:"visible";
            }

      else
        alert("PASS KO")
        }
    </script>
</head>

 <body>

<form action="" name="f1">
    Password : <input type="password" name="senha1" size="20">
    <br>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="senha2" size="20">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Validar" onClick="validarSenha()">
</form>

<form action="#" method="post" name="cadastro" style="display:none">

 </br><hr></br>

    <fieldset class="grupo">
           <div class="campo">
               <label for="nome">Name</label>
               <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" style="width: 20em" value="" />
           </div>
           <div class="campo">
               <label for="cro">CRO</label>
               <input type="text" id="cro" name="cro" style="width: 5em" value="" />
           </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4aq3gd5w/

Eu preciso que a FORM cadastro aparece quando a senha foi definida.

eu tentei com :

```
document.getElementbyId("cadastro").style.visibility:"visible";
```

mas não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dei uma editado no seu codigo pois tinha muitos erros de escrita.
Para selecionar um elemento em javascript, prefira sempre usar o id(document.getElementById) alias voce estava escrevendo o 'byId' com o b minusculo e é maiusculo (getElementById).
Segue o codigo funcionando:

Função javascript:

```
function validarSenha(){

    senha1 = document.getElementById("senha1").value;
    senha2 = document.getElementById("senha2").value;

    if (senha1 == senha2) {
        alert("PASS OK");
        document.getElementById('cadastro').style.display = 'block';
    }

    else {
        alert("PASS KO");
    }
}
```

E adicione o id="senha1" e id="senha2" aos inputs, e id="cadastro" ao form escondido.

Comment: Obg ! Esta OK assim.

Answer (score 2):

utilize a mesma propriedade que utilizou no form para torna-lo invisivel... ou seja o `display`:

```
document.getElementbyId("cadastro").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Obrigado, màs ainda não aparece.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade não é `visibility` e sim `display` tenta assim:

`if (senha1 == senha2) {
   alert("PASS OK");
   document.getElementbyId("cadastro").style.display="block";
}`

Alias seu codigo no jsfiddle está tem um erro de escrita no começo:

`docuemnt.getElementbyName("cadastro").style.visibility:"visible";`

 esta escrito docuement em vez de document.

Comment: Estava testando seu codigo no link que voce mandou e percebi que o metodo onClick no botao nao esta funcionando.<br>Não sei se é erro do jsfiddle mas faça um teste colocando um alert() no inicio da funçao pra ver se o evento onClick esta funcionando.

Comment: Obrgado mas ainda não esta funçionando

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é uma espécie de hide and show, aqueles famosos botões "esconder/mostrar", mas adaptando para as suas necessidades.

http://codepen.io/victorgomes98/pen/GZrzQP

Comment: Obrigado eu preciso disso sem botão.

Comment: @Victor Gomes, poderia adicionar o código diretamente na resposta? e apenas citar a execução do codepen? Assim não corre o risco das pessoas invalidarem por ser uma resposta apenas por link! Obrigado pela compreensão!